# Where can I see when and why my comment was deleted?

Tags: support, status-completed, comments, moderation

I had someone, I believe it was a mod, lazily flag a short, but valid answer of mine. If I recall correctly, I inquired (angrily) about the reason. Later I added some background to the answer to satisfy the complaint.

https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/330118/51035

My comment is gone. Where is it. Who deleted it? Why was it deleted?

I have had this happen in the past on another answer, asked in chat and got no reply: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/50844752#50844752

This gives me a very bad feeling of power abuse by moderators.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, the flag came from the review queue, your comment  was flagged. First I looked and declined the flag as I felt it wasn't "unkind", a 2nd moderator looked at it and agreed with you and deleted both comments.

Your later comment was subsequently deleted by a moderator as it wasn't really relevant to the answer.

As for your chat question, if you don't mention the moderators we don't necessarily see a chat comment, but I'd try to avoid getting furious over flags, we review dozens a week and I (at least) decline more than half of the ones I see. Getting cross with other users or the volunteer moderators will not improve your (or our) enjoyment of the site.

Answer (score 4):

As [commented by @Midavalo](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5077/where-can-i-see-when-and-why-my-comment-was-deleted#comment10745_5077):

> The comment about your answer being too short was added through the
>   review queue. That reviewer deleted the comment after you had expanded
>   your answer. This is a sign of the review queue doing its job.

In addition to that and [@IanTurton's answer](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5078/115) there are some links that I think are worth reviewing with respect to comment use and deletion of comments:

- [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work) which includes:

> **When should comments be deleted?**
>
> Comments are temporary "Post-It" notes left on a question or answer.
>   You should not expect them to be around forever. Once a clarification
>   has been made, an edit added to the post to include new information,
>   or the issue in the comment is otherwise resolved, it is subject to
>   deletion. In reality, many obsolete or chatty comments remain
>   untouched due to the high volume of comments posted, but this does not
>   mean that they can't or shouldn't be deleted in the future.

- https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment which includes:

> **When should I comment?**
>
> You should submit a comment if you want to:
>
> - Request **clarification** from the author;
> - Leave **constructive criticism** that guides the author in improving the post;
> - Add relevant but **minor or transient information** to a post (e.g. a link to a related question, or an alert to the author that the
>     question has been updated).

- [Let us view our deleted comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187279/let-us-view-our-deleted-comments) which is a feature request with [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) for the functionality that you seem to be seeking.